# Can I use brand names in my video game?

Tags: copyright, software, trademark, firearms, branding

I'm currently developing a video game set in the Old West and I'm wanting to know if I can use period gun brand names in my game: Colt, Winchester, etc. Do I need special permission from the companies themselves or what? I won't be using the companies' logos and the use of their brands would only appear in the the names of certain guns, e.g. Colt m1902, Winchester m1887.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you use the names. Generally, if you use them in a positive way and don't make any outrageous claims no one will bother you.

Check this article out about what writers generally do.
http://accentuateservices.com/archives/567

If you are in doubt, just contact the brand. The only real way to know if they will take issue with it is to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the article you linked really helped clarify things.

Comment: Why does it have to be mentioned in a positive way? For example, if you review a product, you are allowed to say something negative about it if that thing is true. And no, you don't need permission to do that.

Comment: An honest review is different than making something sound bad for the purpose of a video game.